# Help writing regular expression for validation in asp.net mc 2

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-2

I need my users to input very specific cell phone format cause my app will be sending sms to them

So, I need their cell phone formats to be like this

04AB-XXXXXXX

Where A can be either 1 or 2

and B can be either 2, 4 or 6

X can be from 0-9
There must be exactly 7 numbers (X) after 04AB

It must always start with 04

> Examples:
>
> 04140000000 allowed
>
> 04240000000 allowed
>
> 04340000000 not allowed
>
> 14240000000 not allowed
>
> 04170000000 not allowed

So my property would need a regular expression validator but I wouldnt even know where to start... I just got this from a tutorial but it's for a different format

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\$?\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$")]
```

this needs to be as strictly as possible because its gonna be used for text messaging.
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need this:

```
^04[12][246][0-9]{7}$
```

That is withouth the "-"

```
^04[12][246]-[0-9]{7}$
```

is with the "-" and

```
^04[12][246]-?[0-9]{7}$
```

allows to use the "-" or leave it

the 0-9 can be replaced with \d like (I like [0-9] for beginners readability):

```
^04[12][246]-?[\d]{7}$
```

so it can become something like:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^04[12][246]-?[0-9]{7}$")]
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, for saving my day from clumsiness and bad grammar ;)